# Umbrella fabric material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am trying to make a material for the umbrella cloth. They have a specific sheen and reflective nature almost like silk and they tend to stand out from other type of clothes. I've been trying to achieve such a look but, I am not very good at materials and no matter what I tweak, it either looking rubbishly rubberish or not like an umbrella cloth material.

Here's one with general reflective surface which looks too smooth and not umbrella like:
I used IOR of .95 for this:

[image]

I searched up that umbrella was made of nylon and it's IOR was 1.5 so I put that and, well:
[image]

The first one obviously looks better, but not close to an umbrella material but unless we view it from a reflective angle:

[image]

Please provide me insight on creating this umbrella material which looks most realistic and physically correct.

I've attached the .blend file with the hdr.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the *Sheen* effect is not enough maybe you should plug an *Input* > *Layer Weight* > *Fresnel* in the factor of a *Mix* between a *Glossy* and a *Diffuse* (or a *Principled BSDF*). To give transparency mix with a *Translucent* node before the end, the fabric will only seem transparent if you face the light source. Also maybe you should use a *Wave* node to create a discrete polyester fabric texture (just some parallel stripes).

[image]

Comment: although, there is no transmissive factor here, the umbrella wouldn't transmit? Do you have any suggestions on how to add the transmission without affecting the texture?

Comment: OK you are right, I've edited to give it a bit of transparency (translucency in that case)